# Categorisation of verbs

Tags: verbs

I am confused about verbs. Have seen the following categorisation:

```
Past Simple
Past Perfect
Past Continuous
Past Perfect Continuous
Past Subjunctive
```

I understand that Past is a Tense. But what about the second categorisation ? Is it Mood, or something else. Are there any great books about description of such things about grammar ? Would this be linguistics ? Nothing too complicated though.

Have encountered `Oxford Guide to English Grammar` and `Cambridge Grammar of English`. How do they compare ?

Comment: Also asked on [ell.se] https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/341958/categorisation-of-verbs/341960#341960  (and previoulsy closed on ELU)

Comment: You're using traditional grammar terms, but not from any one coherent tradition. So, *where* did you see this list; it isn't from a linguistic source. There is no "past subjunctive" in English, there's just a past.

Comment: Continuous and non-continuous is _aspect_. Subjunctive is _mood_. Perfect is tricky, it's _the category of perfect_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subjunctive is a *mood*, the others (perfect, continuous, "simple"=non-continuous) that complement "past" are *aspect*. Never mind that some grammar books speak of "continuous tense", that is an imprecise use of "tense".

You could start reading here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_aspect#English

A great book about such stuff is Wolfgang Klein: Time in Language, Routledge 1994. If you have access to a good library, otherwise it is hard to find.

Comment: The English perfect is less about aspect than it is a marker of relative tense, shifting the time of reference. If it marked perfectiveness, then it wouldn't make sense to combine it with progressive aspect, which is commonly done.

Comment: A relative tense may be called an aspect, depending on the theory...

Comment: Hopefully as linguists we can dissuade people from doing that so that aspect can just have one sensible meaning.

Comment: @curiousdannii It’s not at all uncommon among linguists to consider the English perfect an aspect. CGEL acknowledges this with no objections, though they prefer to consider it tense – something which many here consider anathema. Note that _perfect_ and _perfective_ are two different aspects – the perfect marks _perfectness_ (= past action with present relevance/focus), not perfectiveness (= no internal structure).

Comment: @Alazon There is no subjunctive mood in Presentday English; in fact English does not have a mood system; it was lost in earlier stages of the language. Today, mood is mainly marked by modal auxiliaries with irrealis "were" being an untidy relic of the old system. Btw, 'simple' (or just 'past) and 'perfect' are tenses, not aspects.

Comment: "simple past" is a combination of tense (i.e. past) and aspect, just as its opposite "past progressive". -- The subjunctive is common in written American English, and British "should" etc. in the same function is an auxiliary, but likewise a mood marker. Just as progressive aspect is signalled by an auxiliary.